# Main() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I know that I need to pass 'path' and 'window' to 'main', but I can't quite figure out how this can be done.

[image: python 3]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.

Comment: main("your path with forward slashes", window) ?

Comment: The question was consisting mostly of code, and stackoverflow didn't allowed me to leave it that way.

Comment: @Coelll then you should specify and elaborate your question to allow the code to be apart of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main()` function you defined has two arguments: `path` and `windows`. When calling `main()` at the last line, you should fill in the two parameters with the appropriate objects.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I can't just pass them into main because path and window need to contain something (which was already declared earlier in load_image).
And now I want to be able to pass those 'path' and 'window' into 'main'.

Comment: @Coelll What do you mean? Where have you defined the `path` and `window` parameters anywhere in your code?

Comment: In the load_image function.

Comment: @Coelll `load_image` accepts the `path` and `window` variables. I still don't see it defined anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` only uses path and window in one place: when calling `load_image`. I suspect you should always use `newwindow` in `main` and not pass it in from top-level (in other words, eliminate the `window` arg from `main`). On the other hand, `path` is probably something you want the user to enter on the command line, so you probably want to get it from the argv. But for a quick test, you could hardcode it in line 76.

Comment: About path: user enters his path to files in the textbox (something like a textbox and then he can browse all images in the chosen directory).

Comment: A question for you to answer as you think about this: what image should be loaded when the "Generate Certificate" event is fired? A new image from `path`, or one of the existing images?

Comment: 'Generate certificate' just adds text on the chosen image.

Comment: It doesn't look like that's what your current implementation does. Currently on that event you load some image. Maybe you want to use `images[location]` instead of `path` there? That's the path to the current image.